DateTimeOffset Ticks is bugged or not?
I used a sorted list like that: SortedList<DateTimeOffset, Something>.
The data is well sorted according to the UTC date-time, which is expected.
But "Ticks" is bigger (for DST - for case of Daylight Saving Time) for the previous DateTimeOffset than the next one? How's that possible? It seems to be illogical to me.
Could it be a bug? Anybody knows why or the rule about it?
Image:

Dump of the debug window


  **kvpCurrent.Key**  {2020-11-01 01:00:00 -05:00}    System.DateTimeOffset





  Date    {2020-11-01 00:00:00}   System.DateTime



  DateTime    {2020-11-01 01:00:00}   System.DateTime
  Day 0x00000001  int
  DayOfWeek   Sunday  System.DayOfWeek
  DayOfYear   0x00000132  int
  Hour    0x00000001  int



  LocalDateTime   {2020-11-01 01:00:00}   System.DateTime
  Microsecond 0x00000000  int
  Millisecond 0x00000000  int
  Minute  0x00000000  int
  Month   0x0000000b  int
  Nanosecond  0x00000000  int



  Offset  {-05:00:00} System.TimeSpan
  Second  0x00000000  int
  Ticks   **0x08d87e01753e2800**  long



  TimeOfDay   {01:00:00}  System.TimeSpan
  TotalOffsetMinutes  0xfffffed4  int



  UtcDateTime {**2020-11-01 06:00:00**}   System.DateTime
  UtcTicks    0x08d87e2b5e143000  long
  Year    0x000007e4  int



  Static members      



  Non-Public members      





  **kvpPrevious.Key** {2020-11-01 01:55:00 -04:00}    System.DateTimeOffset





  Date    {2020-11-01 00:00:00}   System.DateTime



  DateTime    {2020-11-01 01:55:00}   System.DateTime
  Day 0x00000001  int
  DayOfWeek   Sunday  System.DayOfWeek
  DayOfYear   0x00000132  int
  Hour    0x00000001  int



  LocalDateTime   {2020-11-01 01:55:00}   System.DateTime
  Microsecond 0x00000000  int
  Millisecond 0x00000000  int
  Minute  0x00000037  int
  Month   0x0000000b  int
  Nanosecond  0x00000000  int



  Offset  {-04:00:00} System.TimeSpan
  Second  0x00000000  int
  Ticks   **0x08d87e0924323200**  long



  TimeOfDay   {01:55:00}  System.TimeSpan
  TotalOffsetMinutes  0xffffff10  int



  UtcDateTime **{2020-11-01 05:55:00}**   System.DateTime
  UtcTicks    0x08d87e2aab43d200  long
  Year    0x000007e4  int



  Static members      



  Non-Public members      




Sorry, I just see it when I revised my question.
There is an UtcTicks property!!!! Sorry!!!
I will let it there just in case someone would do the same mistake as me!!!
